# (Reactive)Mongo test failing with: unrecognised field 'snapshot'

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, bitbucket-pipelines

My tests running in BitBucket pipeline 'suddenly' started to fail with this error: unrecognised field 'snapshot' (code = 9).

Locally the test all run fine though.
Both locally and in BitBucket I'm using a Mongo 3.7 docker container.
Reactive Mongo version is 0.13.0

Anyone have an idea why this happens and how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Finally found the problem.
Apparently I want **not** running Mongo 3.7 locally, but an older version.

The latest ReactiveMongo version (0.13.0) is **not** compatible with Mongo > 3.4. The 'snapshot' field thing apparently was introduced in Mongo 3.7. Even though while not supported officially, Mongo 3.6 did work.

So solution was to downgrade the Mongodb version to 3.6 (or lower)

Comment: You can add a feature request on GitHub for ReactiveMongo

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Joost de Boer answer, using version 0.16.0 it's working for me:

libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.16.0-play26"

Even though I'm using play framework I'm pretty sure it is fixed in 0.16.0 driver level